# How to make the dictionary return a list value?

Tags: python

Write a get_phone_numbers_for_countries function that will:

Receive a list of phone numbers.
Sanitize (normalize) the received customer phone list using our sanitize_phone_number function.
Sort phone numbers by the countries indicated in the table.
Return a dictionary with lists of phone numbers for each country as follows:

```
{
    "UA": [<phone list here>],
    "JP": [<phone list here>],
    "TW": [<phone list here>],
    "SG": [<phone list here>]
}
```

If it was not possible to match the phone code with known ones, this phone should be added to the dictionary list with the key 'UA'.

My code:

```
def sanitize_phone_number(phone):
    new_phone = (
        phone.strip()
        .removeprefix("+")
        .replace("(", "")
        .replace(")", "")
        .replace("-", "")
        .replace(" ", "")
    )
    return new_phone


def get_phone_numbers_for_countries(list_phones):
    dct = dict()
    for num in list_phones:
        num = sanitize_phone_number(num)
        if num[:3] == '380':
            dct.update({"UA": num})
        elif num[:2] == '81':
            dct.update({"JP": num})
        elif num[:2] == '65':
            dct.update({"SG": num})
        elif num[:3] == '886':
            dct.update({"TW": num})
        else:
            dct.update({"UA": num})
            
    return dct
```

The function returns an invalid value: {'UA': '380998759405', 'JP': '818765347', 'TW': '8867658976', 'SG': '657658976'}. Should be: test_get_phone_numbers_for_countries(['380998759405', '818765347', '8867658976', '657658976']) == {'UA': ['380998759405'], 'JP': ['818765347'], 'TW': ['8867658976'], 'SG': ['657658976']}

Help fix the code

Comment: `dct.update({"UA": [num]})` ?

Comment: Btw, use `num.startswith("380")` instead slicing.

Comment: Olvin Roght, I did as you said, the auto-check of the bot does not pass ([])

Comment: num.startswith("380") slicing outputs True or False but I need the exact value as shown in the example

Comment: Autocheck of the bot? You need dictionary where values are lists with single item so I suggested you how to make it. Also I recommended to use `str.startswith()` because you don't actually need to slice first N chars from string manually for comparison as there is already built-in method which checks whether substring present on the beginning of string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because dict.update replaces the values of the dictionary with the values of the dictionary passed as parameters.

To add them I could advise you :

```
def sanitize_phone_number(phone):
    new_phone = (
        phone.strip()
        .removeprefix("+")
        .replace("(", "")
        .replace(")", "")
        .replace("-", "")
        .replace(" ", "")
    )
    return new_phone


def append_number(dct, country, num):
    if country not in dct:
        dct[country] = []

    dct[country].append(num)


def get_phone_numbers_for_countries(list_phones):
    dct = dict()
    for num in list_phones:
        num = sanitize_phone_number(num)
        if num[:3] == "380":
            append_number(dct, "UA", num)
        elif num[:2] == "81":
            append_number(dct, "JP", num)
        elif num[:2] == "65":
            append_number(dct, "SG", num)
        elif num[:3] == "886":
            append_number(dct, "TW", num)
        else:
            append_number(dct, "UA", num)

    return dct
```

Et avec `get_phone_numbers_for_countries(["380998759405", "818765347", "8867658976", "657658976"])` j'obtiens : `{'UA': ['380998759405'], 'JP': ['818765347'], 'TW': ['8867658976'], 'SG': ['657658976']}`

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.update` which will replace the previous value with your new one. Instead you could use `dct["UA"] += [num]`

Also if your else statement adds the number to UA then you don't need the first condition of your if statement